# Postcss-simple-vars is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, postcss

I've been at this problem fro quite some time and can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have created _variables.css file which hold all my CSS variables. I use one of the variables in _global.css on the body tag. However, the styling isn't applied. I have attached screenshots. Thank you. [_variables.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29Ew.png).    [_global.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3UX.png).   [styles.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZolUp.png) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89FD1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using css preprocessors variables so you have to change file extensions to be `.scss`, also you need to compile your `.scss` files to `.css` , [check this guide](https://sass-lang.com/install)

or you can use css variables with different syntax , just like that

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: coral;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```